# Business Intelligence and OLAP/MDX

Tags: mdx, olap, business-intelligence

What are good (no vendor related) blogs about Business Intelligence and OLAP/MDX ?

Edited: To widen a bit the scope and after the answer of Boyan: blogs/forums related to information visualization and Business Intelligence ?

Comment: You can check the asnwers for this question -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4657977/what-are-good-online-communities-portals-about-business-intelligence-solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the rest of the links in Skarab's comment:

I don't think you will find technical (i.e. MDX/OLAP) blogs which are not vendor-specific. Maybe one site that stands out imho is Kimball's http://www.kimballgroup.com/. The articles and the discussions are often vendor-agnostic and you can get some really good knowledge, too.

Otherwise, for "soft"-er topics, you can read Stephen Few's blog on information visualisation.

Comment: Thanks for the info about Stephen Few blog.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Metatron Discovery](https://metatron.app) and its [documentation](https://metatron-app.github.io/metatron-doc-discovery/en/discovery/part01/overview.html#bi) about OLAP & 4th generation BI related to their solution.

Also, it's a bit vendor specific but they kind of well organized the idea of OLAP engine. Cause they use [Druid](https://druid.io) for their underlying processing engine.